# OR-Tools CVRP with delivery and collection of goods at same location

Tags: or-tools

I want to model a CVRP with reloads where goods are shipped from the depot to a location, and other goods are collected at that same location and brought back to the depot. Vehicles have a maximum capacity (e.g. 30 pallets). Sometimes a vehicle picks up more goods than it dropped off at a location.

Here is an example list of loads:

| load id | number of pallets |
| --- | --- |
| Depot → A | 20 |
| A → Depot | 8 |
| Depot → B | 5 |
| B → Depot | 12 |
| Depot → C | 5 |
| C → Depot | 2 |
| Depot → D | 25 |
| D → Depot | 10 |

And this is a valid tour:

| Tour stop / leg | vehicle details |
| --- | --- |
| Start at Depot | Pick up 30 pallets |
| leg "Depot → A" | Carrying 30 pallets |
| Stop at A | Drop off 20, pick up 8 |
| leg "A → B" | Carrying 18 |
| Stop at B | Drop off 5, pick up 12 |
| leg "B → C" | Vehicle load: 25 |
| Stop at C | Drop off 5, pick up 2 |
| leg "C → Depot" | Vehicle load: 22 |
| Stop at Depot | Drop off 22, pick up 25 |
| leg Depot → D | Carrying 25 |
| Stop at D | Drop off 25, pick up 10 |
| leg D → Depot | Carrying 10 |
| End at Depot | Drop off 10 |

Note that the tour *A → B → C* is valid, but *B → A → C* would be invalid because the vehicle capacity would be exceeded at leg *B → A* (more goods are picked up than dropped off at location *B*).

The [CVRP reload example](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/ortools/constraint_solver/samples/cvrp_reload.py) uses a `Capacity` dimension with slack to model reloads, but I believe that slack cannot be used in my situation, is that correct?

Here is what I did instead:
I create one node for the pick-up task, and another node for the drop-off task. The pick-up node increases the `Capacity` dimension by the amount of pallets, and the drop-off node decreases the capacity by the same amount. The arc cost between tasks at the same location is 0. In the example above, this results in a total of 16 nodes: "Depot: Load pallets for A", "Depot: Load pallets for B", ... "A: Unload pallets from depot", "A: Load pallets for depot", ...
Then I apply the constraints from the *CVRP with reload* example to ensure the tasks are visited in the correct order and by the same vehicle.

I don't merge nodes at the same location (e.g. the pick-up and drop-off nodes at *A*) because it's possible that I need to deliver 2x20 pallets to A, which requires two separate tours.

The problem I see with this approach is that my search space is growing to an excessive level: If a vehicle picks up *n* loads, the solver can choose between *n!* possible assignments just at the depot; all of these assignments are logically equal, and have the same objective value.

My next idea is to add a constraint that unloading nodes must be visited before loading nodes, and that nodes of the same type (loading/unloading) must be visited in ascending node order. The constraint must only apply to nodes performed during the same stop (all nodes that have the same arrival time).
This will eliminate duplicate solutions. However, it requires the creation and evaluation of many more constraints, and my understanding of the solver is too limited to estimate whether this would bring any performance improvements.

I'd appreciate any insights, links to articles that explain the OR-Tools internals in detail, or alternate approaches how I can model my problem.

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at the vrp Collect and delivery example.
The trick is to use two dimensions, to track:

- items to deliver, currently loaded in the vehicle.
- total number of items in the vehicle for the capacity constraint.

https://gist.github.com/Mizux/5617f65a7be19449fa475cf04b45e50a